# Bar Stack Category Column

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following implementation:
http://jsfiddle.net/7dhb4jh0/1/

Even though I have data for men and women category, all data displayed in one column. Women category is missing.

```
   {
     "series": "item5",
     "category": "Men",
     "value": 54
   },
   {
     "series": "item7",
     "category": "Women",
     "value": 50
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the grouping to work, you need the same item names for men and women:

```
{
 "series": "item5",
 "category": "Men",
 "value": 54
},
{
 "series": "item5",
 "category": "Women",
 "value": 50
},
```

### Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7dhb4jh0/3/)**

Comment: Any idea for the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675620/remove-legend-color-boundary