# Remove legend color boundary

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following implementation. It works and functional.

However, I want to remove legend color boundary which is black. I could not able to figure out how?

```
 var marker = new kendo.drawing.Path({
    fill: {
        color: color
    }
  }).moveTo(10, 0).lineTo(10, 10).lineTo(0, 10).lineTo(0,0).close();
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/1ost124j/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `stroke` ( border color )  same as you set the `fill`

```
var marker = new kendo.drawing.Path({
  fill: {
    color: color
  },
  stroke: {
    color: color
  }
}).moveTo(10, 0).lineTo(10, 10).lineTo(0, 10).lineTo(0,0).close();
```

You could also remove the `stroke` by setting its color to none.

```
stroke: {
  color: "none"
}
```

or

```
stroke: {
  color: ""
}
```